# Can you set a 1st party cookie in an Iframe you control on another domain - SAAS

Tags: cookies, product, analytics, third-party-cookies

I run a plugin that allows merchants to improve and extend their ecommerce platforms. I have been told I can set 1st party cookies to track the interactions of users within my iframe.

Please can someone explain how this would be achieved? My previous understanding would be that I would always be deemed 3rd party, but I now doubt this to be accurate.

I am most likely going to go down the route of local storage, but this means I need to re-baseline my analytics which I share with the merchants via a dashboard. Local storage doesn't solve the multi-session issue that cookies do.

Does anyone else have this issue and how have they resolved it?

Many thanks